# How to reuse code in CMake

Tags: linux, cmake, code-reuse, reusability

I've got the following piece of code which gets the current system IP and stores it in the `SERVER_IP` variable:

```
EXECUTE_PROCESS(
    COMMAND ip route get 8.8.8.8
    COMMAND awk "NR==1 {print $NF}"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE SERVER_IP
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
```

I need to use this IP several places in my `CMakeLists.txt` file hierarchy. What's the best approach to reuse this code? My first thought is to make it a function like `function(GetIP)`, but I am not sure where to put this function to make it visible to all CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: Do you want to reuse the result of the function or be able to call it from lots of other places?

Comment: @ypx I think reusing its result would be sufficient.

Comment: in that case ComicSansMS's answer using PARENT_SCOPE is more relevant. I would suggest making this clearer in the question.

Answer (score 5):

If you make the CMake function available in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file, it will be also available in the `CMakeLists.txt` files of the subdirectories you added with `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY`.

Either define the function directly in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file or use something like `INCLUDE(GetIP.cmake)` there.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer and it's the write solution for reusing CMake code. However, it turns out Meysam was looking accessing the same variable from multiple locations, something in the direction of variable scope.

Answer (score 3):

If it's just about the IP itself, just put it in a variable.

Variables set in a directory are inherited by all subdirectories, but not by parent directories. You can extend the scope of a local variable by one level with the `PARENT_SCOPE` parameter of the [`set` command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/set.html).

Alternatively, put the variable in the cache to make it accessible globally. Unless marked as internal, this will also make the variable configurable via the CMake GUI.

```
 set(MY_SERVER_IP 8.8.8.8 CACHE STRING "IP address of the server responsible for X")

 [...]
 EXECUTE_PROCESS(
     COMMAND ip route get ${MY_SERVER_IP}
     COMMAND awk "NR==1 {print $NF}"
     OUTPUT_VARIABLE SERVER_IP
     OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
 )
```

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong, but the cache variable defined as above in the root CMakeLists.txt file is not known in the *.cmake file included in one of the other CMakeLists.txt files down the hierarchy.

Comment: @Meysam Note that local variables of the same name hide variables from the enclosing scope. Other than that, there's not much that can prevent you from seeing a cache variable. Please ensure also that the variable has indeed the expected value in the cache - apart from a few special cases, CMake does not overwrite variables already set in Cache unless you use `FORCE`.